# Created a Dictionary in Python with Empty Lists - How to Fill it with Values from Another List?

Tags: python, loops, if-statement

I have a data set that contains `lists` of pairs of numbers, for instance:

```
[[12, 1523], [12, 3533], [12, 12], [15, 242], [15, 4243], [15, 15]...]
```

I have a corresponding dictionary which takes the unique first number in each pair and currently has a blank list associated with the numbers. I.e. this:

```
dict = {key: [] for key in list}
```

First couple of examples:

```
{12: [], 15: [],..}
```

What I want to do is take all the unique values from the list and put them as values in the dictionary. I.e. I'd like this output:

```
{12: [1523, 3533], 15: [242, 4243],...}
```

I was thinking perhaps an if statement. E.g. if the second number within a list pair matches the key, put it in the dictionary. If the value matches the key (e.g. 12 matches the key 12, don't add it to the dictionary). But I'm not sure how to write this in code. Any ideas?

Comment: This code `dict = {key: [] for key in list}` should trigger a TypeError since you can't have lists as keys in dictionary. Are you sure this works?

Answer (score 1):

Use for loop and list indexing operations. Try the below code.

```
a = [[12,1523], [12,3533], [12,12], [15,4243], [15,15]]
d = {k[0]:[] for k in a}  # This sets the keys in dictionary

for item in a:
    key = item[0]
    value = item[1]
    if key != value:
        d[key].append(value)    # We are updating the list with new value, indexing with the key

print(d)
```

Comment: This solution almost works, but returns `{12: [1523, 3533, 12], 15: [4243, 15]}` rather than `{12: [1523, 3533], 15: [4243]}`, the latter of which is the aim. Any thoughts on this detail? @Mithilesh_Kunal

Comment: Added a check to verify if the key is same as value. This should work.

Answer (score 0):

The method [`d.setdefault`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault) returns the value of the chosen key if it found it, otherwise it returns a default value. Therefore, the code below assigns to the key the value that was there beforehand, and append as the value to the list.

```py
l = [[12, 1523], [12, 3533], [12, 12], [15, 242], [15, 4243], [15, 15]] # ...]

d = dict()
for n, m in l:
    # n, m = 12, 1523
    d[n] = d.setdefault(n, list()).append(m)
    # d[12] = d[12].append(1523) if 12 in d.keys() else [1523]
```